# Custom content type for creating a portfolio page

Tags: wordpress

How can I get to the *Settings → Writing → Your Custom Content Types* in WordPress Admin? I do not see the option *Your Custom Content Types*.

I setup my WordPress locally and it is version 4.1. Am I missing anything? Here is the tutorial I am trying to follow for the portfolio: http://en.support.wordpress.com/portfolios/